# Zoom in and out in mapKit using slider

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location, uislider

I have a map view where I display the user's current location and all the other locations I have. I want to zoom in and out using a slider,
for example the user wants to display the locations that are 1km away from his current location. How can implement that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement some sort of biasing, but here is what I have used in the past (using Google's MapViewKit):

```
mapView.animate(toZoom: MySlider.Value * Bias)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. the Bias should be based on what ? how to determine it ?